# How Do I dim/disable the current view?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

Is it possible to dim the current view in cocoa?On a certain action I want to make the screen a little darker and prevent the user from interacting with the screen.

Comment: Please clarify the scope; is it the view or the screen?

Comment: The entire application window

Comment: So neither.  You need to be more precise.

Comment: The current view which is visible to the user

Comment: @trojanfoe I have to dim the image(Make it very dark/blackish) and disable all controls on the screen

Comment: You'll have to subclass the view and add a "reduced functionality mode".  When in this mode you need to ignore user input (disable all subviews) and perhaps draw the rest of the view in some darker way (see `drawRect:`).

Comment: I was able to disable the view by using [self.view.window setignoremouseevents:YES].How do I reduce the brightness of the image?

Comment: Perhaps draw a layer over the top of all the subviews when in this mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the idea given by @Lord Zsolt, the same can be implemented in OS X as:

Add the following code when you want to darken your window.

```
NSView *transparentBlackView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:[[yourwindow contentView] frame]];

CALayer *viewLayer = [CALayer layer];
[viewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4)]; //RGB plus Alpha Channel
[transparentBlackView setWantsLayer:YES]; 
[transparentBlackView setLayer:viewLayer];

[[yourwindow contentView] addSubview:transparentBlackView];
```

**Also don't forget to add `QuartzCore.framework` to your project. And import it in your class using `#import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`**

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: I've only now noticed, it's OSX, not iOS. Though the idea should still be the same.**

Disable user interaction:

```
[self.view setUserIntractionEnabled:NO];
```

Then add a UIView with black color, alpha like 0.2 above it.

```
UIView *transparentBlackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]
[transparentBlackView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor];
[transparentBlackView setAlpha:0.2];
[self.view addSubview:transparentBlackView];
```

Then you can write a custom method, and use performSelector:afterDelay to remove transparentBlackView.

Comment: Yeah they are the same apart from missing the key method `setUserIntractionEnabled`...

Comment: Yes, I said they don't work in OSX, but there probably is an OSX counterpart for each.